# How to use jQuery and 'this' to capture changed form element value

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have the following code that works each and every time an element change happens within my web form:

```
<!--

jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and versions

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(this).change(function(){
        alert('form element changed!');
    });

}); // end .ready()

//-->
```

What I have been struggling with is how to capture the *form field element* **id**, **name** and **changed value** when the change event is triggered.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Thanks!

** JAVASCRIPT FILE **

```
// Sarfraz
$(this).change(function(){
   var id, name, value;
   id = this.id, name = this.name, value = this.value;
    alert('id=' + id); // this returns 'undefined'
    alert('name=' + name); // this returns 'undefined'
    alert('value=' + value); // this returns 'undefined'
});
//

// rjz
$(this).change(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
    id = $this.attr('id'),
    name = $this.attr('name'),
    value = $this.val();

    alert(id); // this returns 'undefined'
    alert(name); // this returns 'undefined'
    alert(value); // this returns blank
});

// Jamie
$(this).change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).attr('value');

    alert('id=' + id); // this returns 'undefined'
    alert('name=' + name); // this returns 'undefined'
    alert('value=' + value); // this returns 'undefined'
});
//

//James Allardice
$(this).change(function(e) {
    var elem = e.target;
    alert('elem=' + elem); // this returns 'objectHTMLTextAreaElement'
});
//

// Surreal Dreams
$("#my-form input").change(function(){
    alert('form element changed!');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var name = $(this).attr("name");

    alert(id); // nothing happens
    alert(name); // nothing happens
    alert(value); // nothing happens
});
//

//Jamie - Second Try
$('.jamie2').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id); // nothing happens
    });
});
//
```

Comment: What is `this` in your example?

Comment: "this" is a reserved word in javascript, correct?

Comment: Yes, but it's meaning is contextual.

Comment: You typically use $(this) inside code related to a selected element, for instance, inside an event handler to refer to the element that had the event.

Comment: @Dr.DOT, when referenced outside the scope of a jQuery event handler (and a few other methods), `$(this)` is typically invalid (unless you're setting this to something else). You should use a selector instead, as shown in Surreal Dreams' answer.

Comment: I revised my initial code sample to show the full scope of my .js file in order to reply to [at]SurrealDreams and [at]jrummell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand it, `this` refers to a `form` element and you want to get a reference to the descendant of that `form` element which triggered the event.

If that's right, you can use the `target` property of the event object:

```
$(this).change(function(e) {
    var elem = e.target;
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2fCeB/16/).

In the above code, `elem` will refer to the element which triggered the event. You can then access properties of that element, such as `id`:

```
$(this).change(function(e) {
    var elemId = e.target.id;
});
```

Comment: I got 'objectHTMLTextAreaElement' when I tried your sample. See code I appended to my question.

Comment: @Dr.DOT - Try `alert(e.target.id);`. `e.target` gets you the actual element. You can then access properties of it. I've updated my answer with another example.

Comment: YAHOO @JamesAllardice. You got me the closest thus far. I just saw the ID name. I am going to play around some with your sample. I'll report back. You're a star. So is everyone else who chimed in here. Thanks Everyone!!!

Comment: @Dr.DOT - Glad you made some progress :)

Comment: @JamesAllardice...I just alerted the changed value for the first time in like 3 days of wheel spinning. Thanks so much !

Comment: If you have a moment, I have my next question as I build my app. Can you peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593517/prettyphoto-how-to-capture-form-elements-that-are-part-of-inline-text-lightbox and tell me if you have any ideas on my next issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think you may have a problem right from the start:

```
$("#myform input").change(function(){
    alert('form element changed!');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
});
```

You don't want to start with $(this), you need to select the inputs you want to monitor.  Then you can use $(this) inside the change() function.

James Allardice pointed out that you may be referring to the form with $(this), and the change() event would catch all changes in the form.  I'd suggest you target your changed elements more specifically so you're not catching change events on elements that you don't need or want, which could eliminate unexpected behavior.  You could target them with a class or form selector like `:input`.

Comment: I'll agree with this one until Dr. DOT provides additional information for why you would want to bind change to "this" rather than to particular inputs. ;-) I can't think of a good use case for `$(this).change()` yet, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: @GregPettit - Since `this` refers to a `form` element, you can bind a `change` event handler to it and it will capture change events triggered by any descendant of it (as they will bubble up to the `form`). Like using `on` with a selector argument. See my answer.

Comment: If Dr. DOT provides some clarification, I'll be sure to make an update.  Toss a comment down here Dr. DOT so I get a note to check it.

Comment: @SurrealDreams - nothing happened when I tried your suggestion. See my code I appended to my answer

Comment: @JamesAllardice Gotcha; I was thinking of `this` as being the input, not the form. However, I still think selecting the form elements and binding change to them is easier than fiddling with 'this' as the starting point.

Comment: @GregPettit - It may be easier, but if there are lots of `input` elements it's far less efficient (you have one event handler instead of one for every single `input`).

Comment: @JamesAllardice True fact. You could always delegate the form as a listener for change events on inputs for the same net result but less confusing syntax (subjectively speaking, mind you).

Comment: @GregPettit - That's exactly what you would be doing if you bind the `change` event handler to the `form`. It's basically the same as doing `$("#myForm").on("change", "input", someFunction);`.

Comment: @SurrealDreams. Thank you very much for helping me out. I was able to get what I set out too via James Allardice's `e.target.id` answer. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use $(this), you must have a predefined JavaScript object.  That's why it's called *this*.

So you need to do something like this:

```
$('.class_name').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

or

```
$('.class_name').click(function() {
    $(this).change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

In short, you need to select an element and create an object before you can use $(this).

Comment: @Jaimie. each of your sample code returns 'undefined'. See the code I appended to my question.

Comment: Thanks @Jaimie...but still no luck. See my code I appended to my question.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I was able to get what I set out too via James Allardice's `e.target.id` answer. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like the following inside your change

```
var ELEMEMT = $('#IDOFELEMENT').val();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I was able to get what I set out too via James Allardice's `e.target.id` answer. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the properties directly as follows:

```
$(this).change(function(){
  var id = this.id,
    name = this.name,
    value = this.value;
});
```

Alternatively, jQuery provides helper functions to retrieve these properties from the first element in a jQuery collection:

```
$(this).change(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
    id = $this.attr('id'),
    name = $this.attr('name'),
    value = $this.val();
});
```

Comment: Your first example is identical to Sarfraz. Your second example I tested as well. Both samples return undefined. See my JS code in my question.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I was able to get what I set out too via James Allardice's `e.target.id` answer. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

TRY with jQuery 1.7

```
$(document).on('change','#myID',function(){
    alert('Id:'+this.id+'\nName:'+this.name+'\nValue:'+this.value);
});​
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/Unnuf/)

Comment: I assumed #myID is in reference to my <form> tag id. Correct? If so, nothing returned when I tired your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I was able to get what I set out too via James Allardice's `e.target.id` answer. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
$(this).change(function(){
   var id, name, value;
   id = this.id; name = this.name; value = this.value;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Sarfraz. I tried your version a few days ago, but gave it another shot. See my code that appended to my question. All three elements return "undefined".

Comment: @Dr.DOT: You need to also clarify what does `this` refer to in your code, what html element and how does it reach till that code.

Comment: @Dr.DOT: Yes but one can make it refer to objects in JS. That's what I am asking what object does it refer to? Or an element that you are grabbing with jQuery? You need to edit that information in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I was able to get what I set out too via James Allardice's `e.target.id` answer. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Best regards.

Comment: @Dr.DOT: You are welcome and glad to know that your problem was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm late to the party except in comment form, but just for posterity: here's my extension of Surreal Dreams' approach:

```
$("#myform").on('change', input, (function(){
    alert('form element changed!');
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.val();
    var id = $this.attr("id");
    var name = $this.attr("name");
});
```

#myform listens for changes on inputs inside. I also cached the jQuery-wrapped `this`. Voila!